# Does Linux still support any other binary formats besides ELF?

Tags: linux, elf

Does Linux still support any other binary formats besides ELF? For example, COFF and a.out formats.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can still enable a.out in the Kernel configuration. The kernel parameter for that is `CONFIG_BINFMT_AOUT`.

Comment: For kernel v4.8, `CONFIG_BINFMT_AOUT` is available on a few architectures.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can often mimic support for other formats using emulators + binfmt kernel feature. E.g. for Windows PE's you can use [wine-binfmt](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2016-August/114478.html).

Comment: `CONFIG_BINFMT_MISC` is not supported on all architectures. A grep of `CONFIG_BINFMT_MISC` in kernel source v4.8's arch directory shows that it is only available on some architectures.